# rotating a div element onmouseenter and stop rotation onmouseleave

Tags: javascript, html, css

i searched a lot but i'm unable to understand the implementation(i'm beginner).so please help me with this.

```
   <div id="card" style="height:100;width:100;background-color:blue" 
          onmouseenter="start('1')" onmouseleave="start('0')"  >

   </div>
```

javascript:

```
     var x=0;
     var y;
     function start(d)
    {
       if(d=='1')
          y=setInterval(function(){rotate()},10);
       else
       {
        clearInterval(y);
       }

   }
   function rotate()
   {
      x+=1;
      x=x%360;
      document.getElementById("card").setAttribute("style","-webkit- 
            transform:rotateX("+x+"deg)");
   }
```

here i'm trying to rotate the div element onmouseenter and to stop rotation onmouseleave but it is not working  properly

Comment: Like instead of i.e: `a += a+b` you can do: `a += b` wollowing the same syntax you can do `x %= 360` which is the same as `x = x%360`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i will change that in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were overwritting the original styles for the card causing it to disappear. I'd suggest you don't use inline styling, it's a bad practice. You also had an error there: `height:100;width:100;`. Unlike tag attributes, CSS properties for height and width need to have a unit, so `height:100px; width:100px;` is okay.

```
document.getElementById("card")
    .style["-webkit-transform"] = "rotateZ(" + x + "deg)";
```

Here is the working version of your code (note that I changed the rotation to the Z-axis instead, it just made more sense): http://jsfiddle.net/34JKj/1/

Another idea: you can also define an infinite rotating animation with CSS, bind it to a certain class, and then just add/remove the class to your element upon mouse enter/leave. CSS performs much better than JS and has become a standard, so it's something worth thinking about.

Comment: i'm extremely sorry actually they are setInterval and clearInterval

Comment: No problem, I should've figured it out. I'll delete my answer, but I'll try to fix your code first.

Comment: I modified your code a bit, see the working version of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/34JKj/ (note: you might want to use `rotateZ` instead, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/34JKj/1/)

Comment: can u give me a brief description of what changes you made

Comment: Ah, those are 3d transformations... They are a bit more complex. At this point, I can only recommend you a tutorial like this one: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip  Basically, it's related to the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @saimadan getting over and over an element inside a loop at 10ms it's a really bad idea

Comment: @shomz actually i wanted to implement few transitions which i saw in this website "www.techfest.org".once look at the transitions for that div's "initiatives","competitions"....(in website).i started to implement keeping that in mind but i got stuck.BTW you people helped me a lot thank you very much

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan actually i wanted to implement few transitions which i saw in this website "www.techfest.org".once look at the transitions for that div's "initiatives","competitions"....(in website).i started to implement keeping that in mind but i got stuck.BTW you people helped me a lot thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, see my previous comment for a tutorial link. It will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UModeHu/3/edit)**

HTML:

```
<div id="card"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#card{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

JS:

```
var x=0;
var y;
var $card = document.getElementById("card");

function start(){
      y = setInterval(rotate,25);
}
function stop(){
   clearInterval(y);
}

function rotate(){
   $card.setAttribute(
     "style","-webkit-transform:rotate("+ (++x % 360) +"deg)"
   );
}

$card.addEventListener('mouseenter', start, false);
$card.addEventListener('mouseleave', stop, false);
```