# On array of nav elements, onmouseenter rotate element (like a wheel) and onmouseleave the wheel stops?

Tags: javascript

I hope the way I've explained it in the question makes sense. Basically I have a fullPage.js nav on the left hand side made up of circles with wheels as background images. I want each nav link to spin/rotate onmouseenter and stop in it's tracks onmouseleave. But I don't want the animation to reset to it's initial state hence why I'm using JS otherwise I would use css animations.

In an ideal world I would also want the link to the current or 'active' section spin continuously and stop where it was (not reset) if another nav link is clicked and the clicked link to start. But I have been on this for a couple of days and will settle for just the basic onmouseenter and onmouseleave functionality at this point which is why you won't see any 'active' element defined in the code below.

Currently I'm just getting the wheel jumping in rotation and not rotating continuously.

Rotating code borrowed from answer here: [rotating a div element onmouseenter and stop rotation onmouseleave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513799/rotating-a-div-element-onmouseenter-and-stop-rotation-onmouseleave)

Thank you!!!

```
const fullPageNav = document.getElementById('fp-nav');
const fullPageNavLinks = fullPageNav.getElementsByTagName("a");
const fullPageNavLinksArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(fullPageNavLinks);
let x = 0;
let y;

function start() {
      y = setInterval(rotate, 25);
}

function stop() {
   clearInterval(y);
}

for (let i = 0; i < fullPageNavLinksArray.length; i++) {
  fullPageNavLinksArray[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', start, false);
  fullPageNavLinksArray[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', stop, false);
}

function rotate() {
    for (let i = 0; i < fullPageNavLinksArray.length; i++) {
    fullPageNavLinksArray[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        fullPageNavLinksArray[i].style.transform = 'rotate(' + (++x % 360) + 'deg)'; 
        fullPageNavLinksArray[i].style.transition = 'none';
    });
}
}

<div id="fp-nav" class="fp-left fp-show-active">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="active spinme" transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
                <span class="fp-sr-only">Section%201</span>
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="spinme" transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
                <span class="fp-sr-only">Section%202</span>
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="spinme" transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
                <span class="fp-sr-only">Section%203</span>
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think instead of calculating the necessary current rotation value inside an interval, it would make much more sense, if you used a normal, infinite CSS animation for this - and then on mouseenter/-leave, you simply toggle the element's `animation-play-state` between `running` and `paused` via JS ...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you @CBroe I feel kinda stupid now!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @CBroe for the easier answer. Use animation-play-state/animationPlayState instead of trying to be clever with setInterval.

```
const fullPageNav = document.getElementById('fp-nav');
const fullPageNavLinks = fullPageNav.getElementsByTagName("a");
const fullPageNavLinksArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(fullPageNavLinks);

fullPageNavLinksArray.forEach(fpnla => {
     fpnla.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        fpnla.classList.add('hovering');
    });
    fpnla.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        fpnla.classList.remove('hovering');
    });
});

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#fp-nav ul li a {
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

#fp-nav ul li a.active {
    animation-play-state: running!important;
}

#fp-nav ul li a.hovering {
    animation-play-state: running!important;
}
```